# Writing CSS right before the closing body tag

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to write one line of CSS using vanilla JavaScript inside the `document.body`, but right before the closing `</body>` tag.

What am I doing wrong, why isn't this working?

```
document.body.write('<style type="text/css">#input, #backgroundFix{ background:url(dawn.svg) top left repeat-x; }</style>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s `document.write`, not `document.body.write`, assuming your script is also right before the closing `</body>` tag.

If not, use `document.createElement` instead.

Comment: what is the difference? document.body is still a javascript object that can call the write function, right?

Comment: @IrfanMir: No, `write` is exclusive to document objects. Did you check the error console? It should explain that the `write` method of `document.body` doesn’t exist. `write` is for writing raw HTML to the currently rendering document; it’s not really related to the DOM tree.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for explaining. Am not getting that error in the error console in chrome, though.